# How to read the result of pandas merge?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

Using pandas merge, the resulting columns are confusing:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 5)))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 5)))

df2[0] = df1[0]  # matching key on the first column.

# Now the weird part.
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=0, right_on=0).shape
Out[96]: (5, 9)
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).shape
Out[102]: (5, 10)
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=0, right_on=1).shape
Out[107]: (0, 11)
```

The number of columns are not fixed, the column labels are also unstable, worse yet these are not documented clearly.

I want to read some columns of the resulting data frame, which have many columns (hundreds). Currently I am using .iloc[] because labeling is too much work. But I am worried that this is error prone due to the weird merged result.
What is the correct way to read some columns in the merged data frame?

Python: 2.7.13, Pandas: 0.19.2

Comment: If merge dataframes with same names in `df1` and `df2` there are added suffixes. So first if merge by first column get 4 same columns (join column is same) so output is `9` columns. In second merge by index, so output is 10 columns. Last merge by different columns (default inner join) so sometimes it return some data, sometimes nothing (because random data).

Comment: If columns names are different, shape of dataframes is different, there is very hard find some general solution for easy selecting.

Comment: @jezrael: So merging on 2 columns with the same label will delete 1 column? And merging on 2 columns with different labels will add 1 'key_0' column?
What if I don't manage the label of columns?

Comment: @jezrael: Turns out there are cases when merging 2 columns with different labels does not add column 'key_0'. The mechanism get really confusing.

Comment: I dont down vote To your first question - no delete, it only create one joined column - get values with df1, then `df2` and create column with values which are in both dataframes.

Comment: @jezrael: I know you did not down vote, I just ask the anonymous person ;-). I understand your point about the joined column (as well as 5nv's point about the join-key column). The problem is that, this is not distinguishable from other case. So I end up checking for each case by the number of columns in merged dataframe, then use different indexing number in .iloc[]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with 3 different cases for the number of columns in merged result, I ended up checking the number of columns, then convert the column number index to use in .iloc[]. Here is the code, for future searchers.

Still the best way I know to deal with huge number of columns now. I will mark the better answer if there is one.

Utility method to convert column number index:

```
def get_merged_column_index(num_col_df, num_col_df1, num_col_df2, col_df1=[], col_df2=[], joinkey_df1=[], joinkey_df2=[]):
    """Transform the column indexes in old source dataframes to column indexes in merged dataframe. Check for different pandas merged result formats.

    :param num_col_df: number of columns in merged dataframe df.
    :param num_col_df1: number of columns in df1.
    :param num_col_df2: number of columns in df2.
    :param col_df1: (list of int) column position in df1 to keep (0-based).
    :param col_df2: (list of int) column position in df2 to keep (0-based).
    :param joinkey_df1:  (list of int) column position (0-based). Not implemented now.
    :param joinkey_df2:  (list of int) column position (0-based). Not implemented now.
    :return: (list of int) transformed column indexes, 0-based, in merged dataframe.
    """

    col_df1 = np.array(col_df1)
    col_df2 = np.array(col_df2)

    if num_col_df == num_col_df1 + num_col_df2: # merging keeps same old columns
        col_df2 += num_col_df1
    elif num_col_df == num_col_df1 + num_col_df2 + 1: # merging add column 'key_0' to the head
        col_df1 += 1
        col_df2 += num_col_df1 + 1
    elif num_col_df <= num_col_df1 + num_col_df2 - 1: # merging deletes (possibly many) duplicated "join-key" columns in df2, keep and do not change order columns in df1.
        raise ValueError('Format of merged result is too complicated.')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Undefined format of merged result.')

    return np.concatenate((col_df1, col_df2)).astype(int).tolist()
```

Then:

```
cols_toextract_df1 = []
cols_toextract_df2 = []
converted_cols = get_merged_column_index(num_col_df=df.shape[1], num_col_df1=df1.shape[1], num_col_df2=df2.shape[1], col_df1=cols_toextract_df1, col_df2=cols_toextract_df1)
extracted_df = df.iloc[:, converted_cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Merge key**

1.1 Merge on key when the join-key is a column (This is the right solution for you as you say "df2[0] = df1[0]  # matching key on the first column.
")

1.2 Merge on index when the merge-key is the index
 ==> reason why you get 1 column more in the second merge  (pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).shape) is because the initial join keys appears now twice '0_x' & '0_y'

**Regarding column names**

Column names do not change during a merge, UNLESS there are columns with the same name in both dataframes. The columns change like following, you get :

- 'initial_column_name'+'_x' (the suffix '_x' is added to the column of the left dataframe (df1))
- 'initial_column_name'+'_y' (the suffix '_y' is added to the column of the right dataframe (df2) )

Comment: I noticed the changed column label, but the problem is that after some merging, the labels are messed up. Moreover, as I said the number of columns is large, so I use iloc[] to get data.

Comment: I'm still not clear about what columns will be deleted or added and what are the rules. And how to get, say columns 1 of df1 and (3, 4) of df2, from the merged data frame?

Comment: 1 possible solution I am thinking of is checking the shape of the merged data frame, then process in three cases. But is there any better way that follow pandas documentation?

Comment: 1: No columns will be deleted. The only columns which are added to the dataframe are the columns of the dataframe you merge with. The join-key also does not become duplicated.

Comment: Regarding choosing the columns: pd.merge(df1[['join_key','column_1']],df2[['join_key','column_1','column2','column_3,left_on='join_key',right_on='join_key) ==> result: dataframe with the columns['join_key','column_1_x','column_1_y','column_2','column_3]

Comment: For deleted columns, I meant 1 'joint-key' will be deleted, because actually these joint-key columns are just logical joint-key, they are just columns and don't necessarily have the same meaning (like TransactionID). I see how your example works for small data frame, but I have too many columns, I cannot manage all labels after many merging operations.