# Pandas Merge avoid key_0 column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am merging 2 dataframes on different column names which I don't want to change. However, it creates a separate key_0 field.

```
dict_1 = {'Col1':['A1','A2','A3','A4','A1','A3','A4'],
        'Col2':['B1','B1','B2','B3','B2','B4','B4'],
        'Col3':[i for i in range(10,17)],
        'Col4':[i for i in range(20,27)],
        'Col5':[i for i in range(30,37)],
        'Col6':[i for i in range(40,47)]}

dict_2 = {'Col11':['A1','A2','A1','A4'],
        'Col12':['C1','C2','C4','C3'],
        'Col13':[i for i in range(12,16)],
        'Col14':[i for i in range(21,25)],
        'Col15':[i for i in range(32,36)],
        'Col16':[i for i in range(41,45)]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)
```

Then I merge them as follows:

```
pd.merge(left=df_1,right=df_2['Col12'],left_on=df_1['Col1'],right_on=df_2['Col11'],how='left',suffixes=(None,None))
```

And I get this output with an extra column key_0

```
    key_0   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col12
0   A1  A1  B1  10  20  30  40  C1
1   A1  A1  B1  10  20  30  40  C4
2   A2  A2  B1  11  21  31  41  C2
3   A3  A3  B2  12  22  32  42  NaN
4   A4  A4  B3  13  23  33  43  C3
5   A1  A1  B2  14  24  34  44  C1
6   A1  A1  B2  14  24  34  44  C4
7   A3  A3  B4  15  25  35  45  NaN
8   A4  A4  B4  16  26  36  46  C3
```

How to avoid that key_0 column in the same merge method?

I can rename the joining columns but that's practically not possible when large & multiple dataframes to be worked upon.
I can modify the code to drop the column like this:

```
pd.merge(left=df_1,right=df_2['Col12'],left_on=df_1['Col1'],right_on=df_2['Col11'],how='left',suffixes=(None,None)).drop(labels='key_0',axis=1)
```

But that's an extra step & sometimes I need to merge multiple columns separately from different dfs. Is there any other argument present in the method that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can make small change in you merge to get desired output. Just provide column_name[dont include dataframe] for left_on, right_on parameter.

```
pd.merge(left=df_1, right=df_2[['Col11', 'Col12']],left_on=['Col1'],right_on=['Col11'],how='left')
```

There is some explanation on this why column gets added, you can check out - [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482366/how-to-read-the-result-of-pandas-merge)

Comment: I tried that, it still adds 'Col11' from df_2 again, which is redundant column that I don't want

Comment: Then you have only work around is to rename your column in df_2 'Col11' to 'Col1'. So that you can join it using on keyword only... like
pd.merge(left=df_1,right=df_2[['Col1','Col12']],on=['Col1'],how='left',suffixes=(None,None))